# Get the current active screen route of the tab navigator in react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

This is my navigation stack using react navigation *v3.2.1*:

1. I have a switch navigator to switch to Authentication navigation stack and Authenticated App stack.
2. The App stack is made using a bottom tab navigator.
3. I would like to use a custom component for the tab navigator.

How do I get the current routeName of the tab navigator when using `createBottomTabNavigator` and a custom `tabBarComponent`.

Eg:

1. Suppose the tab navigation stack has 2 navigation screens, i.e., Home and Chat.
2. Inside the custom BottomBar, how do I check if the focused/active/current routeName is Home/Chat so that I can change the style of icons respectively?

AppContainer.js

```
const switchStack = createSwitchNavigator({
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
})

export default createAppContainer(switchStack)
```

AppStack.js

```
const AppStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeStack,
    },
    Chat: {
        screen: ChatStack
    },
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    activeColor: '#f0edf6',
    inactiveColor: '#3e2465',
    shifting: false,
    barStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#694fad',
    },
    labeled: false,
    tabBarComponent: ({navigation}) => <BottomBar navigation={navigation}/>
})

export default AppStack
```

BottomBar.js

```
export default class BottomBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <IconComponent routeName={'Home'}/>
                <IconComponent routeName={'Chat'}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

IconComponent.js

```
export default class IconComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    ...

    render() {
        let IconComponent
        let iconName
        let iconSize = 25
        switch (this.props.routeName) {
            case 'Home':
                IconComponent = MaterialCommunityIcons
                // iconName = `home${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
                iconName = `home`;
                break
            case 'Chat':
                IconComponent = AntDesign
                iconName = `message1`
                iconSize = 22
                break
        }

        let tintColor = 'green'

        // if focused Home is current tab screen then change style eg. tint color.
        // similary if current tab screen is Chat, then change style.

        return (
                <Animated.View
                    style={[
                        styles.container,
                        {
                            opacity: this.opacity
                        }
                    ]}
                >
                    <IconComponent name={iconName} size={iconSize} color={tintColor}/>
                </Animated.View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

navigation object of your custom BottomBar has an index that hold the current active screen index

```
tabBarComponent: ({navigation}) => <BottomBar navigation={navigation}/>

navigation.state.index
```

If Home screen is active >> navigation.state.index would be 0
If Chat screen is active >> navigation.state.index would be 1 ...etc

Comment: I suppose this might actually work for my use case. I investigate further and get back soon.

Comment: This is the right solution actually, I have tried it and it is working fine and fits to my use case

Answer (score 6):

Using a functional component with React Navigation 5.x. You can use the **useIsFocused** hook.

```
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
```

Usage: In each of the tab screens that you want to detect if they are the currently active or focused.

```
const isFocused = useIsFocused();

if (isFocused) {
  // the screen is currently focused
  // your code here
}
```

Docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/

Answer (score 4):

You can with `navigation.state.routeName`

```
tabBarComponent: ({navigation}) => <BottomBar navigation={navigation} currentRouteName={navigation.state.routeName} />
```

Or Better still you can do something like this:

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: Home,
    Chat: Chat
},
{
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
            if (navigation.state.routeName === 'Home') {
                return <Icon name='ios-home' size={30} color={tintColor} />
            } else if (navigation.state.routeName === 'Chat') {
                return <Icon name='ios-heart' size={30} color={tintColor} />
            }
        },
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#2BEDBA',
            inactiveTintColor: '#FAFAFA',
            style: { backgroundColor: '#000', paddingTop: 5 }
        },
    })
});
```

Comment: I actually tried this way before, but instead of `Home` or `Chat`, this method only returns the `App` stack route name, which is from the top level switch navigator stack.

Comment: the prop `route` moved out from `navigation.state`, it's now: `({navigation, route}) => <BottomBar navigation={navigation} currentRouteName={route.name} />`

Answer (score 4):

Rather than setting a complete new `tabBarComponent` for icons you can use `tabBarIcon` property to set the icons. You can find an example on [Tab Navigation Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html#customizing-the-appearance)

> - `tabBarIcon` is a property on `navigationOptions`, so we know we can use it on our screen components, but in this case chose to put it
>     in the `createBottomTabNavigator` configuration in order to centralize
>     the icon configuration for convenience.
> - `tabBarIcon` is a function that is given the `focused state`, `tintColor`, and `horizontal` param, which is a boolean. If you take a
>     peek further down in the configuration you will see `tabBarOptions`
>     and `activeTintColor` and `inactiveTintColor`. These default to the
>     the iOS platform defaults, but you can change them here. The
>     `tintColor` that is passed through to the `tabBarIcon` is either the
>     active or inactive one, depending on the `focused` state (focused is
>     active). The orientation state `horizontal` is true when the device is
>     in landscape, otherwise is `false` for portrait.
> - Read the [full API reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html) for further information on `createBottomTabNavigator` configuration options.

**Example** *(From the docs)*

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let IconComponent = Ionicons;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
          // Sometimes we want to add badges to some icons. 
          // You can check the implementation below.
          IconComponent = HomeIconWithBadge; 
        } else if (routeName === 'Settings') {
          iconName = `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        }

        // You can return any component that you like here!
        return <IconComponent name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: Yes, this was actually how I was working before. But since I need to add some extra features to the tab bar (e.g. floating action button), I was using a custom component.

Answer (score -1):

As @Biskrem Muhammad suggested, this works:

```js
export function SignUp(props: TSignupProps) {
  const { navigation, route } = props;
  console.log('Im in screen:', route.name)
  .
  .
  .
}
```